# How to avoid empty visit functions in visitor pattern?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

I have the following use case. I have a restriction interface that needs to fill its members from dependencies, do the validations. These methods are applicable for all implementations and hence it is fine till now. Some restrictions require some other validation later. In the main function, I want to loop over each of the restriction and call the methods in a general way instead of using instanceOf and then calling. I think this might be a use case of visitor pattern as mentioned [here](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/visitor#:%7E:text=Use%20the%20pattern%20when%20a%20behavior%20makes%20sense%20only%20in%20some%20classes%20of%20a%20class%20hierarchy%2C%20but%20not%20in%20others.). Now I have the following classes.

```
interface Restriction() {
    void fillFields();
    void firstRoundValidation();
    void accept(SecondRoundValidationVisitor secondRoundValidationVisitor);
}
```

```
class RestrictionBasic implements Restriction {
    Field field;

    // Inject dependencies

    @Override
    void fillFields() {
        // Get field from dependencies
    }

    void firstRoundValidation() {
        // Implement
    }

    @void accept(SecondRoundValidationVisitor secondRoundValidationVisitor) {
        secondRoundValidationVisitor.visitRestrictionBasic(this);
    }
}
```

```
class RestrictionAdvanced implements Restriction {

    // Same as above except below function.

    @void accept(SecondRoundValidationVisitor secondRoundValidationVisitor) {
        secondRoundValidationVisitor.visitRestrictionAdvanced(this);
    }
}
```

```
interface ValidationVisitor {
    void visitRestriction(RestrictionBasic restrictionBasic);
    void visitRestriction(RestrictionAdvanced restrictionAdvanced);
}
```

```
class SecondRoundValidationVisitor implements ValidationVisitor {
    @Override
    void visitRestriction(RestrictionBasic restrictionBasic) {
        // Empty function
    }

    @Override
    void visitRestriction(RestrictionAdvanced restrictionAdvanced) {
        // Perform second level of validation
    }
}
```

```
class Main() {
    List<Restriction> restrictionList = new ArrayList();
    ValidationVisitor validationVisitor = new SecondRoundValidationVisitor();
    for (restriction : restrictionList) {
        restriction.accept(validationVisitor)
    }
}
```

Could you please tell if there is any issue with this approach? There is also another approach where getSecondValidationNeeded() could be added to the interface and based on that, call secondValidation with default value of empty body. But this is not following interface segregation principle. My doubt is how does visitor pattern solve this issue? Even in visitor pattern, there is only one interface and accept is being added in base interface even when only some visitors have non empty visit functions.

Answer (score 1):

Pattern-wise I don't think there is a problem. visitRestrictionBasic is only empty because apparently you don't have second round validation for basic restrictions. This is a business rule, not a flaw of the design. If you later decide that you DO want second round validation for basic restrictions, you know where you can add it.

Apart from that, the whole set up might be overkill. It's usually good to start off simple. But I don't know your complete domain and use case, so cannot judge if this is the case here.

EDIT: To evaluate your approach we should get more context and take a step back to understand the problem. So far what I understand is there are several restriction types which have the following characteristics:

- each restriction has a fixed groups of dependencies
- a restriction extracts values from these dependencies into its fields
- each restriction performs two rounds of validation on these fields
- the first round validation is implemented in each restriction type
- the second round validation is also specific per restriction type, but implemented in the form of a separate visitor

The fundamental difference between the first round and second round validation is not clear to me. Both of them have specific validation code for each restriction type if I understand it correctly. If not, and the basic validator is only used in the first round, and the advanced validator only in the second round, then the model could probably be simplified. In that case first round = basic and second round = advanced...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you please tell why you think it is overkill, you mean it is okay to use instanceOf if the number of if conditions are small in number and this visitor pattern is only required when there are many if conditions?

Comment: No I don't think you should use instanceOf to solve this - that's a bad code smell. But I don't know which problem you are exactly trying to solve. If the domain is simple and the number of cases is small it might be possible to achieve what you want with less code constructs. To know that, I would need some more background information.

Comment: Thanks, could you please tell what more information exactly you need? I thought I added the information needed in the question which is to iterate over a list of interface objects and call a function for each, but this function is only possible for some of the implementations not all.

Comment: Your question is very broad: "Is there any issue with this approach?". To know if the approach is good, we need to know which problem we are solving. You didn't present us with the problem, but only with the solution you came up with. So how many restriction types are there? What do they do? How different are they? Why is the first round validation completely general but the second round specific per restriction type? Is the process of first round/second round still up for debate, or is that fixed? Could the concerns of injecting/calling dependencies and validation maybe better be extracted?

Answer (score 1):

Visitor pattern uses overloading of methods to choose appropriate implementation. It can be seen in a [wiki example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern):

```
interface CarElementVisitor {
    void visit(Body body);
    void visit(Car car);
    void visit(Engine engine);
    void visit(Wheel wheel);
}
```

So I would edit interface `ValidationVisitor`:

```
interface ValidationVisitor {
    void visitRestrictionBasic(RestrictionBasic restrictionBasic);
    void visitRestrictionAdvanced(RestrictionAdvanced restrictionAdvanced);
}
```

to this:

```
public interface ValidationVisitor
{
    void VisitRestriction(RestrictionBasic restrictionBasic);
    
    void VisitRestriction(RestrictionAdvanced restrictionAdvanced);
}
```

So we have created `VisitRestriction()` with different overloads.

Why? If you don't know the type of the object? You probably would need to find out the real type of `Restriction` and then call `VisitRestrictionBasic` or `VisitRestrictionAdvanced`. I highly recommend you to read this very nice answer about *[What's the point of the `accept` method](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/412367/202970)*?

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. I have already given this only or the following in my question right?

```
interface ValidationVisitor {
    void visitRestrictionBasic(RestrictionBasic restrictionBasic);
    void visitRestrictionAdvanced(RestrictionAdvanced restrictionAdvanced);
}
```

Comment: Oh sry got it, I missed using same overloading the function and instead used separate function. Thanks for catching, could you please tell if there is some other issue in the approach overall and some other approach is better?

Comment: Empty function is required to add `accept(SecondRoundValidationVisitor secondRoundValidationVisitor)` in the interface right? And this is required for iterating and calling specific functions not there in some classes without using instanceOf.

Comment: @GopikrishnaKS  so I have just one improvement. Please, see my updated answer. Thanks!